# How to use machine name instead of localhost:9200 through API call in elastic search

Tags: api, elasticsearch

I'm doing API call with url: http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search?q=**searchdata**. Now I want to call through machine/computer name instead of localhost. How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement nothing,
use the next URL:
http://computer_name:9200/index/type/_search?q=searchdata

If it's not working be sure that the port not blocking by firewall or something like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Elasticsearch is listening on the network interface you want to connect to. By default Elasticsearch listens only on localhost. You can configure the [network.host setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/important-settings.html#network.host) to change this.